# HTML <video> function if videoEnded go to other section of the page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page here which shows a video at load. What I am trying to achieve is; If the video has ended, go to other section of my page (like the button does).

http://i333180.iris.fhict.nl/p2_vc/#section1

Already collected some code from the internet but couldn't make it functional.
Didn't found that much for my problem tho.

**HTML**

```
<!-- video -->
<video id="moodvideo" autoplay controls onended="videoEnded()">
    <source src="moodvideo.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
</video>
```

**JS**

```
function videoEnded() {
    //go to a hreff="#section"
}
```

Comment: is your function called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<video id="moodvideo" autoplay controls onended="videoEnded()"  src="moodvideo.mp4"></video>
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function videoEnded() {
      window.location.href="http://i333180.iris.fhict.nl/p2_vc/#section"; }
</script>
```

Since it's referring to the section on the same page you could also simplify thing by passing section name only as argument to the method.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         function videoEnded(sectionName) {
          window.location.href=window.location.pathname+"/#"+sectionName;
         }
 </script>
```

Comment: @JimVercoelen, you're welcome and nice site there ;)

Comment: @Felvy Pallar Thanks, thanks, still noob, just started it study:P